# When logging into i3 WM with GWM login loop

Tags: 12.04, login-screen, i3-wm

After I boot up and attempt to login from GWM with i3 WM selected, the screen goes blank for a few seconds then goes back to the login-screen. I can login with any other WM, such as unity, gnome.etc

Answer (score 2):

Press `ctrl+alt+f2` then type your user name, press enter; then type your password and press enter.

Now you should be loged into your account in the console.  Now type `nano .xinitrc` and press enter. You are now in the nano text editor editing the new file .xinitrc. Now type this line:

```
exec i3
```

Press `ctrl+x`, press `y` and type:

```
startx
```

This will now start i3. To use i3 again, press `ctrl+alt+f2` then type your user name, press enter; then type your password and press enter: and lastly type `startx`.

I recommend reading this first before using i3:

http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html

Hope that helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem (arch-i3wm), so this works for me:

1. press ctrl+alt+f2 (to use te terminal)
2. cd .., cd.., to /
3. cd /etc, cd /X11, cd /xinit
4. run sudo nano xinit.rc
5. above userresources=$HOME.... write "exec i3"
6. save the changes and then run startx

I hope my solution help u, sorry for explanation and my english, if u have dudes tell me here